# How to add a banner/image view on top of UINavigation Bar

Tags: iphone

I wanted to know if there's a way to add some sort of image view on top of the navigation bar. I don't want to cover it, rather, I just want to move the bar down in order to make room for a banner. The myspace app displays a bar right above their navigation bar, and so does the bank of america app. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://www.gamma-point.com/content/adding-banner-above-navigation-controller) - substitute the `UITabBarController` for a `UINavigationController`.